# Microsot Excel - two way mirrored/linked cells with diferent values (one in percentage / another in absolute value)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have A1 cell formatted as currency (e.g. EUR) - in which I manually enter
base value - e.g. 1000 EUR of which I want make further calculations in B1 and C1 cells.
B1 cell is formatted as percentage (e.g. 20%)
C1 cell is formatted as currency format againg (EUR) in which I want to calculate absolute value in EUR (20% of 1000 eur = 200 eur)

However - I want to make B1 and C1 cells to be linked together vice-versa with respective formulas, so which-ever cell (B1 or C1) I enter the value, in other one automatically updates its result, and vice-versa.

E.g. in case if I have 1000 EUR in A1 cell 
a) if I enter 20% in B1, C1 should show result = 200 EUR, and vice vera 
b) when I enter 200 EUR in C1, B1 shoul show result of 20%

Can you please advise How to make this work? I think there is some code needed (VBA). Thank you very much, Dusan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a worksheet event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B1:C1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
            [C1] = [A1] * [B1]
        Else
            [B1] = [C1] / [A1]
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If you update **B1**, the macro will update **C1** to be consistent.
If you update **C1**, the macro will update **B1** to be consistent.
If you update **A1** the macro will wait for you to also update either **B1** or **C1** before making changes.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

Here is the new code.  `TbSize` is the number of rows in the three column table.:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim TbSize As Long, rng As Range, roww As Long
    TbSize = 100
    Set rng = Range("A1:C" & TbSize)

    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    roww = Target.Row
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
            Range("C" & roww) = Range("A" & roww) * Range("B" & roww)
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
            Range("B" & roww) = Range("C" & roww) / Range("A" & roww)
        Else
            Range("C" & roww) = Range("A" & roww) * Range("B" & roww)
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Can you help with improvement of this a bit?                                  1) If I update A1 I would like it not to wait until I update B1 or C1. Could the code be edited/changed so if I update A1 it would not wait untill I update B1 or C1, but It would automaticaly update C1 in accordance to B1 value (percentage)? Could you please advice?

Comment: More over I would also like this to work not only in specific cells (A1, B1, C1) but rather in whole columns, as I need this formulas to be working in large data table. Simple dragging a handle of these specific cells and filing it below to adjescent cells (so it would copy formulas, does not make it work. I this this is because the code refers to those 3 specific cells only. Could you help with this? I really appreciate any help, as this my first vba coding and macro experience so far. Thanks

Comment: @DušanŠebán I will update later today.

Comment: @DušanŠebán  See my **EDIT#1**